# How can i get seperate values of array into same array?

Tags: php, arrays, split

I have a PHP array that I am trying to split into 2 different arrays into that particular array. I am trying to pull out any values for each "destination" and "balance".

Here is the array i get,

```
Array
(
    [destination_1] => 1
    [balance_1] => 1
    [destination_2] => 2
    [balance_2] => 2
    [destination_3] => 3
    [balance_3] => 3
)
```

I need output like,

```
Array  ( 
[0] => Array ( 
             [destination_1] => 1 
             [balance_1] => 1
             ) 
[1] => Array ( 
             [destination_2] => 2 
             [balance_1] => 2
             )   
[2] => Array (
             [destination_3] => 3
             [balance_3] => 3
             )
    )
```

Comment: What have you tried? A simple foreach loop with a counter seems a possibility.

Comment: _I am trying.._ Post what you are trying and what is not working

Comment: @B001ᛦ I've tried array_walk and array_chunk. but seems like none is helping in this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is [array_chunk()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php)

```
$arr = [
    "destination_1" => 1,
    "balance_1" => 1,
    "destination_2" => 2,
    "balance_2" => 2,
    "destination_3" => 3,
    "balance_3" => 3
];

$result =  array_chunk($arr, 2, true);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [destination_1] => 1
            [balance_1] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [destination_2] => 2
            [balance_2] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [destination_3] => 3
            [balance_3] => 3
        )

)
```